# permalink_url property, short url

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, soundcloud

I get JSON from soundcloud and use permalink_url property for initializing my player. Sometimes in permalink_url used short url and I can't get data for this track by https. How and why in permalink_url was short url? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean a short url something like this: `http://snd.sc/abc123`? If so, could you include the request which gives you that short_url? Otherwise if it's a 'normal' url like `http://soundcloud.com/username/track`, you can use the [resolve endpoint](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/resolve) to get the track (or user, or set, etc) data.

Comment: I use request something like this http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json?q=lol&consumer_key=my_key&limit=5&offset=5 Now all good, in permalink_url full url. In this property can be used a shortened URL?

Comment: @daredevil: I'm sorry but I don't understand your question. What exactly do you need? Do you want the 'twitter-friendly' short url which redirects to this full permalink?

Comment: I get tracks JSON from soundcloud by jQuery $.getJSON. And use permalink_url property to init soundcloud custom player. Usually in this property was normal url something like this http://soundcloud.com/username/track. But in one case in permalink_url was short url (http://snd.sc/abc123 for example). User already post player with short url. But player not working by https because short url. And question why in permalink_url was short url?

Comment: @daredevil I've just taken a look at the code which generates the permalink_url and it's not possible that a shortened URL is sent via the API. Could you take another look at your data?

Comment: Hmm, very strange, I check code again, but in it use only permalink_url. Well, I will decide this issue otherwise :) But you can answer me where in the data can be used short url?

Comment: @daredevil I'm sorry, but I still don't understand your question. The short snd.sc url is not resolvable via the API. They are provided by bit.ly, so perhaps you could resolve a short url to the full one if bitly allows that, and then use the API to get the track information.